# Is it possible to TRAIN a neural network model with Tensoflow Lite/Or any other frameworks on smartphones?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow-federated

Is it possible to TRAIN a neural network model with Tensoflow Lite/Or any other frameworks on smartphones?

Specifically in the context for federative learning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check out [Deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/android/setup) which supports Android integration and also on-device training. For a Federated Learning setup, you may think of implementing the Federated Averaging algorithm by yourself on a Java based server, using the same DL4J framework as on mobile clients.

Although, support for on-device training is already on the [Tensorflow Lite roadmap](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/roadmap) for some time, so it is a matter of time until TFLite will provide it's own solution.

Answer (score 2):

[TensorFlow Federated](http://www.tensorflow.org/federated) is a framework for machine learning and other computations on decentralized data (i.e. federated learning). TFF currently supports running *research simulations* for learning algorithms involving fleets of mobile devices, but *does not* currently provide a platform necessary to deploy such on-device training.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the pointers but I found that the framework doesn't support physical devices(Android phones) yet. All runs are in simulations on a Local Machine (Based on their FAQs)